# Remote SQL Server backups using Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I've got a handful of databases running on a SQL Server instance. I don't have access to be able to install the Azure Backup agent but I do have connection details and credentials to access the database and perform backups in SQL Server Management Studio.

What I want to do is be able to perform and schedule these backups and save them in to Azure Blob Storage. I could have this schedule running on my local computer but that's not an ideal solution.

I've got a powershell script that will perform this action for me but it relies on SQL Server assemblies to run. I've tried running this as a devops build task but am unable to do so without the assemblies it requires.

Does anybody know a way of setting this up? In azure for example? Is there a resource that will allow me to connect and backup a sql instance via connections string and save down to blob storage. Or an azure function perhaps?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept(mark) it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a resource that will allow me to connect and backup a sql instance via connections string and save down to blob storage?

I'm afraid the answer is no.

We can't find any API support in Azure to help you achieve that.

I think the SQL Server Management Studio and powershell script is more suitable for you.

Maybe you can think about using third-party tool [SQL Backup and FTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/), it can help you schedule backup the SQL Server to Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies I'd completed neglected this but your answer was indeed helpful - thank you